# get microphone permission in unpackaged Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome Extension in which the microphone keeps listening all the time in lifetime of a Chrome Window.

I am trying to include audioCapture in permissions in manifest.json,

But I get the error:

```
audioCapture' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension
```

What can I do in this?

Is there any other way through which mic keeps listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `getUserMedia()` in content js file or if you want to get permission in manifest.json, try packaging your app and then load it again

Answer (score 0):

`'audioCapture'` permission isn't supported yet for Chrome extensions manifest (see  [chrome extension documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for the complete list).
You can trigger it in your content js files or in popup.js calling `getUserMedia` promise like this:

```
console.log('try trigger authorization');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
.then((mediaStream) => { 
    //in promise will be triggered user permission request                
})
.catch((error) => {
   //manage error
});
```

This workaround works fine for my purpose.